# Let $k, m, n \in\mathbb Z^+$, where $k$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Prove that if $k|mn$ then $k|n$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to complete this question but it has me a little stumped!

Let $k, m, n \in\mathbb Z^+$, where $k$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Prove that if $k|mn$ then $k|n$ ($k|mn$ implies that $k$ divides $mn$ and $k|n$ implies that $k$ divides $n$) .

Comment: Are you familiar with Bézout's identity?

Comment: not really,we haven't learned that in class yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k$ and $m$ have no common prime factors. Therefore, if $k$ divides $m\times n$, it must have common factors with $n$. That's more or less a consequence of the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

Comment: oh wow, it sounds so obvious now lol, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to use FTA for this, there are more elementary ways of showing this

Comment: This is to provide intuition, there are certainly other ways

Comment: @CheeseCracker please accept the answer if you're not looking for anything else